# Firebase hosting, Problema en routing

Tags: python, firebase

Hace poco empecé en firebase y estoy usando la documentación de GCP y firebase, estoy tratando de configurar el routing de /login y /home. cuando trato de modificar me devuelve 404, 304 o 200(index.html no home.html). intente borrar el cache de `.firebase`

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "static",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/login",
        "destination": "/login.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/home/**",
        "destination": "/home.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

mi pagina tiene como base flask y microservicios que interactúan con esta:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        client_id = get_client_id()
        return render_template('static/login.html', client_id=client_id)

@app.route('/home/<path:path>')
def home(path):
    with lock:
        pass
    # execute_email_provider()
    return render_template('static/home.html')
```

replico distintos escenarios con `firebase serve` `firebase emulators:start` `firebase deploy`

Answer (score 0):

edit: logre eliminar el bug despues de añadir

```
"rewrites": [],
"headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```